# AfterTextChanged and OnFocusChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, onfocus

I've got a textwatcher on multiple editText boxes that takes calculations and outputs the result into a Textview.  However, I also need a way to use DecimalFormat so that after the user types it into the editText, it formats it like so: "$###,###,###.00". I've thought about using the OnFocusChangedListener, but this seems like it would still trigger the afterTextChanged event. How would I do this so that I don't end up with a Stack Overflow?

The textwatcher calls a method like this:

```
TextWatcher Watch = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        calc();

    }
private void calc() {
Editable eValue1 = new.getText(), eValue2 = ti.getText(), eValue3 = acc.getText();
Double value1 = 0.0, value2 = 0.0, value3 = 0.0, result = 0.0;

if (eValue1 != null)
    value1 = toDouble(eValue1);
if (eValue2 != null)
    value2 = toDouble(eValue2);
if (eValue3 != null)
    value3 = toDouble(eValue3);
if (value1 != null && value2 != null && value3 != null)
    result = value1 - (value2 + value3);
    td.setText(formatCur(result));

}
  private String formatCur(Double result) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###,###.00");
    String format = df.format(result);
    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the listener, setting the text, then adding the listener again?

Comment: Not sure if that would work.  The listeners are used to dynamically output calculations without the need for a "calculate" button. I've posted the code above if you've got any ideas.

Comment: Just add a private boolean _textModifiedByWatcher = false; which you set to true after changing the text in the watcher. In afterTextChanged you check if _textModifiedByWatcher is true. If it is, you set it to false, and return immediately.

Comment: I tried this but somethings not quite working right. Could you add a simple example? I'm new to android and Java.

Comment: TextWatcher Watch = new TextWatcher() {

   private boolean _textModifiedByWatcher = false;

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (_textModifiedByWatcher) {
           _textModifiedByWatcher = false;
           return;
        }
        _textModifiedByWatcher = true;
        calc();
    }

Comment: No matter what I do, this still triggers Stack Overflow.  Is there a way to use decimalFormat("$###,###,###") in the afterTextChanged listener for the SAME edittext box? Or is there a way to just have the "$" and special characters already in the editText box?

Comment: It looks you are doing something wrong. Please paste your code as an edit to your question so I can help you better.